# Can I define arguments for the CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM in the list files?

Tags: cmake

When I build my project with cmake I usually use the command line

```
cmake --build . -- -j4
```

when using make, or

```
cmake --build . -- /maxcpucount:4
```

when using MSBuild

Repeating this all the time is annoying and I would rather set this in the CMakeLists file instead of writing it in the command line.
I am wondering if there is a cmake variable that can hold additional options for the make tool which I could set to `-j4` or `/maxcpucount:4` depending on which `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM` is used.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use a shell script and a batch file? After all, there could be many options for specific generators.

Comment: See also https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16951

Comment: So reading the links from the comments I get the impression that this is currently not possible, but there is a discussion within the cmake team to make the multicore build the default, which would remove my need for settings these flags.